# rails multiple input record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails. I have some question that's been quite a headache to me, so here it is:

For example i have this controller & view:

Controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @Order = Order.new
  end 

  def create
    @Order = Order.new(params[:order])
    if @Order.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created order."
      redirect_to @Order
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

View:

```
<% title "Menu Order" %>
<%= form_for @Order do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

<div id="form-order">
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name%><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :menu_order %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :menu_order  %>
  </p>   
</div>
<%= f.submit %>
```

So my question is :

before displaying the form above, I want to have a text_field_tag that specify how many forms (roughly said, duplicate the form div) I want to generate based on count, and then insert the data to the database simultaneously,
the idea is to speed things up, so that the user don't have to input the data only one at a time, but multiple record at single submit

How do I do that?

Comment: Are you interesting in using javascript? Or doing everything on the server?

Comment: i think javascript will be okay, i appreciate any solution available :)